# How to push git branch code with credentials from command-line

Tags: git, github

I have changes in a git branch. I want to push those changes to GitHub through one single command like `git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git`

How to achieve same thing when pushing changes of a git branch from the command line?

I tried these two options

- `git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git origin HEAD:development`
- `git push origin HEAD:development https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git`

Comment: Your [deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62612038/how-to-block-any-outside-docker-host-port-say-80-in-ubuntu-linux-vm) could be posted on Server Fault; it seems to be a good question, but is not on-topic here. (I would advise a bit more brevity if you can though - the Stack Exchange sites tend to prefer succinct technical writing wherever possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at `man git-push`, and you will see that the syntax for `git push` is as follows:

```
git push [options...] [<repository> [<refspec>...]]
```

Where `<repository>` is either an URL or the name of a remote. Your command should thus be:

```
git push https://username:password@myrepository.biz/file.git HEAD:development
```

Besides, it should probably say `ssh://` instead of `https://`.